# Pyspark - Lambda Expressions operating on specific columns

Tags: random, lambda, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark dataframe that looks like:

```
+---------------+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|         Entity| id|  7| 15| 19| 21| 27|
+---------------+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|              a|  0|  0|  1|  0|  0|  0|
|              b|  1|  0|  0|  0|  1|  0|
|              c|  2|  0|  0|  0|  1|  0|
|              d|  3|  2|  0|  0|  0|  0|
|              e|  4|  0|  3|  0|  0|  0|
|              f|  5|  0| 25|  0|  0|  0|
|              g|  6|  2|  0|  0|  0|  0|
```

I want to add a random value between 0 and 1 to all elements in every column sans Entity & id. There could be any number of columns after Entity & id (in this case there's 5, but there could be 100, or a 1000 or more).

Here's what I have so far:

```
 random_df = data.select("*").rdd.map(
     lambda x, r=random: [Row(str(row)) if isinstance(row, unicode) else 
     Row(float(r.random() + row)) for row in x]).toDF(data.columns)
```

However, this will also add a random value to the id column.  Normally, if I knew the number of elements before, and I knew they would be fixed I could explicitly call them out in the lambda expression with

```
data.select("*").rdd.map(lambda (a,b,c,d,e,f,g): 
         Row(a,b, r.random() + c r.random() + d, r.random() + e, r.random() 
               + f, r.random() + g))
```

But, unfortunately, this won't work due to not knowing how many columns I"ll have ahead of time.  Thoughts?  I really appreciate the help!

EDIT:  I should also note that 'id' is a result of calling:

```
data = data.withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id())
```

Adding this edit as I tried to convert the column 'id' into a StringType so that my 'isinstance(row, unicode)' would trigger, but I wasn't successful.  The following code:

```
data = data.withColumn("id", data['id'].cast(StringType)
```

results in:

```
raise TypeError("unexpected type: %s" % type(dataType))
TypeError: unexpected type: <class 'pyspark.sql.types.DataTypeSingleton'>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try `.cast("string")` on `id` column.

```
import random
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql.types import Row

df = sc.parallelize([
    ['a', 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    ['b', 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
    ['c', 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
    ['d', 2, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    ['e', 0, 3, 0, 0, 0],
    ['f', 0, 25,0, 0, 0],
    ['g', 2, 0, 0, 0, 0],
]).toDF(('entity', '7', '15', '19', '21', '27'))
df = df.withColumn("id", f.monotonically_increasing_id())
df = df.withColumn("id_string", df["id"].cast("string")).drop("id")
df.show()

random_df = df.select("*").rdd.map(
     lambda x, r=random: [Row(str(row)) if isinstance(row, unicode) else
     Row(float(r.random() + row)) for row in x]).toDF(df.columns)
random_df.show()
```